# error getting the array result in Join Query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hello this is my query and I have the problem getting the result_array().

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\plss\application\views\Admin\post_refresh.php on line 6

```
<?php 
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('forum_thread');
     $this->db->join('useraccount','useraccount.user_id = forum_thread.user_id');
     $post= $this->db->get();  
     foreach($post->result_array()  as $row): ?>    
        <div class="panel panel-default" >
            <div class="panel-body">
               <p>
                  <small>Clinton Puds</small>
                  <small style="float:right;color:#808080;font-size:10px;"><b>Posted Last</b> <?php echo $row['date_last_post']?></small>
                </p>
                <p><?php echo $row['slug'];?></p>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-footer"><small><a href="">Comment</a></small></div>
         </div>     


<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I just solve the problem 
I used something like this.


$query = $this->db->query("select * from forum_thread left join db_useraccount on db_useraccount.user_id=forum_thread.user_id ORDER BY thread_id DESC ");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $post = $this->db->get()->result_array();  
 foreach($post as $row): //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$post->result() as $row
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I just solve the problem 
I used something like this.
 $query = $this->db->query("select * from forum_thread left join db_useraccount on db_useraccount.user_id=forum_thread.user_id ORDER BY thread_id DESC ");